# MPI_Allgather with 2D arrays

Tags: c, arrays, mpi

I am trying to calculate the position of some bodies that is based in their previous positions. So in every k loop I need every C array to be updated with the new coordinates (x,y,z) of the bodies that is calculated and stored in the Cw arrays. I tried MPI_Allgather but I can't find the right syntax to achieve it.

I've checked the output with the serial version of the problem for k=1 and the values of F,V and Cw arrays are right so the only problem is the MPI_Allgather. The dt variable for now is equal to 1 for simplicity. I've tried this but none of ther work. The first one updates only the first row C array right from the Cw and 2 more values but in wrong places and the rest is the same as when is filled in the beginning. The second gives Segmentation fault

```
MPI_Allgather(&(Cw[0][0]),length*3,MPI_FLOAT,&(C[0][0]),length*3,MPI_FLOAT,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

MPI_Allgather(Cw,length*3,MPI_FLOAT,C,length*3,MPI_FLOAT,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Here is the code

```
float **C,**Cw;

C=malloc(N*sizeof(float*));
Cw=malloc(length*sizeof(float*));

for(i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    Cw[i]=malloc(3*sizeof(float));
}

for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    C[i]=malloc(3*sizeof(float));
}


for(k=0;k<loop;k++)
{
    for(i=start;i<=end;i++)                      
    {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)                        
        {
            if(i!=j)
            {
                dx=C[j][0]-C[i][0];
                dy=C[j][1]-C[i][1];
                dz=C[j][2]-C[i][2];

                d=sqrt(pow(dx,2)+pow(dy,2)+pow(dz,2));

                F[i-start][0] -= G*M[i]*M[j]/pow(d,3)*dx;
                F[i-start][1] -= G*M[i]*M[j]/pow(d,3)*dy;
                F[i-start][2] -= G*M[i]*M[j]/pow(d,3)*dz;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            a=F[i][j]/M[i+start];                 // α=F/m
            V[i][j]=V[i][j]+a*1;                 // V(n+1)=Vn+α*Δt
            Cw[i][j]=C[i+start][j]+V[i][j]*1;    // R(n+1)=Rn+Vn*Δt
        }
    }

    // where MPI_Allgather takes place
}
```

The output that I expect is this provided by the serial program
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fwLu8Jk3JEorFTvNJyOtti3K_zIw0ncw

The mpi version with this code

```
MPI_Allgather(&(Cw[0][0]),length*3,MPI_FLOAT,&(C[0][0]),length*3,MPI_FLOAT,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

gives this output https://drive.google.com/open?id=14cEFFRvNGUN_RK3u8Z31iRDtiTJs6_8I

Comment: How did you declare `Cw` and `C` ?

Comment: I added it in the code above @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: You need to allocate your 2D arrays in contiguous memory. You also likely want `N == length * size(MPI_COMM_WORLD)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again this pointers-to-pointers nonsense (for scicomp): you are passing the pointers to the rows via MPI, not the contents.

I suggest that you avoid to allocate an array as N independent rows, as in:

```
float **C,**Cw;

// I guess that you missed to paste these two lines
C  = malloc( N * sizeof(float*) );    
Cw = malloc( length * sizeof(float*) );

for(i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    Cw[i]=malloc(3*sizeof(float));
}

for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    C[i]=malloc(3*sizeof(float));
}
```

The arrays allocated in this way aren't linear in memory, and cannot be used by the MPI functions globally. When you pass `C`, you are passing just the array of pointers. Passing `&C[0][0]`, you are passing the array of the first 3 elements, but the other 3-elements-arrays aren't contiguous in memory, since they've been allocated independently. So a segfault is the best that you can achieve, being random results, the worst.

It's correct to allocate the needed memory in one single block, that MPI function can handle properly:

```
float *C,*Cw;
C  = malloc( N * 3 * sizeof(float) );    
Cw = malloc( length * 3 * sizeof(float) );
```

and replace any memory access as

```
            dx=C[j][0]-C[i][0];
            dy=C[j][1]-C[i][1];
            dz=C[j][2]-C[i][2];
```

with

```
            dx=C[3*j+0]-C[3*i+0];
            dy=C[3*j+1]-C[3*i+1];
            dz=C[3*j+2]-C[3*i+2];
```

In this way, passing `C` will result in passing the array contents correctly.