# MPI_Bcast gets seg. fault with Signal code: Address not mapped (1)

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm trying to broadcast an array of words. More precisely, I'm trying to bcast a dictionary (an hash_map {string,int} ) but of course I cannot do it the easy way. So I'm storing all keys and all values in two separate arrays (cfKeys and cfValues). MAX_CF_LENGTH is the maximum number of characters of a key.

Here's a code snippet:

```
char **cfKeys; // this contains all cf keys in the dataset
int *cfValues; // this contains all cf values in the dataset
int num_cf;
```

[...some preprocessing...]

```
if(myrank == 0) num_cf = cfDictionary.size(); // this is an hardcoded dictionary in a separate header file

MPI_Bcast(&num_cf, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
cfValues = new int[num_cf];
cfKeys = new char *[num_cf];
for (int i = 0; i < num_cf; i++)
    cfKeys[i] = new char[MAX_CF_LENGTH];

if (myrank == 0)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (auto cf : cfDictionary)
    {
        strncpy(cfKeys[i], cf.first.c_str(), MAX_CF_LENGTH);
        cfValues[i] = cf.second;
        i++;
    }
}

MPI_Bcast(cfValues, num_cf, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // no problem here
MPI_Bcast(cfKeys, num_cf * MAX_CF_LENGTH, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // seg. fault here
```

Besides the error, if you think there's a better way to implement this dictonary transfer please do not hesitate to advise me :) Comment if you need more infos/code snippets. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to broadcast `cfKeys ` in one shot, you need to allocate it in contiguous memory instead of using a jagged array.

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58364672/mpi-allgather-with-2d-arrays/58379603#58379603

Comment: You both are absolutely right! I really missed this in the MPI doc... How can I allocate contiguously cfKeys then? Let's say I'm willing to exploit a MAX_CF_LENGTH (as max. num of columns) and same num_cf (as num of rows). Tryed googling a bit but couldn't figure it out. @Sigismondo 's answer doesn't allow me to access the words in one shot (like cfKeys[i * MAX_CF_LENGTH] just gives me the first character of the key).

Comment: `cfKeys = new char [num_cf*MAX_CF_LENGTH];` and then `strncpy(&cfKeys[i*MAX_CF_LENGTH], cf.first.c_str(), MAX_CF_LENGTH);`

Comment: As I said I need to access the key directly with cfKeys[i]. That solution returns me char by char iterating over the array. I found it myself doing `char(*cfKeys)[MAX_CF_LENGTH];` and then     `cfKeys = (char(*)[MAX_CF_LENGTH])malloc(num_cf * sizeof(*cfKeys));`. Still wondering anyway if my solution can be any smarter than this.

Comment: You need to manually build the array of pointers if you cannot    use `i*MAX_CF_LENGTH`

Comment: if yot take care to store in cfKeys - as suggested by @GillesGouaillardet - 0-terminated strings: MAX_CF_LENGTH should consider the 0-termination - then you can just access them: `char *str; str = cfKeys + i*MAX_CF_LENGTH`. What you got with `cfKeys[i]`, is now `(cfKeys+i*MAX_CF_LENGTH)`

Comment: `char **cfPtrKeys; cfPtrKeys = new char* [num_cf]; for (i=0; i<num_cf; ++) { cfPtrKey[i] = cfKeys+i*MAX_CF_LENGTH;}` then you can use `cfPtrKeys[i]` - I didn't undestand you were looking for some syntactical glue to conform to existing code